# Was any of the witches’ magic on ‘American Horror Story’ not one of the Seven Wonders?

Tags: witches, american-horror-story

On *American Horror Story*, witches (and warlocks) appear in (primarily, as far as I recall) in *Coven* and *Apocalypse*.

To assume the role of Supreme, witches must be able to perform all of [the Seven Wonders](https://americanhorrorstory.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Witches/Magic):

1. **Telekinesis**: movement of objects without physical contact
2. **Transmutation**: travelling from one place to another without traversing the space between them
3. **Pyrokinesis**: conjuring and manipulating fire magically
4. **Concilium**: imposing one’s will on another’s mind, including actions but also thoughts and memories
5. **Divination**: obtaining knowledge by means other than the physical senses (not limited to seeing to foreseeing the future as in other worlds)
6. **Vitalum vitalis**: “balancing the scales between one life force and another”; in other words, resurrection and corporal healing
7. **Descensum**: directly entering hell (without dying on Earth) and then returning by one’s own powers

As far as I can tell, any magic the witches (and warlocks) on the show do can be categorised as an example of the above seven abilities.

Does the series show any magic that’s not these categories?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Nice detailed question, but you should consider removing the "bonus" and making it its own question.  As it is, that part is too nebulous and risks derailing the actual question.

Comment: @DavidW Thank you for the welcome, and that is a good call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few occurrences of magic not related to the seven wonders that we see in the show. For example, the first act of magic we see in season 3, Zoe has the *Black Widow* power, she can kill people when having sex with them. It happens twice, the first time with her boyfriend, the second with one of Madison's rapers.
Nan has also a power that is not related to the Seven Wonders, the mind reading.

Queenie has the voodoo doll power, but she is the descendant of the only Salem black witch, so it could be an inheritance of voodoo magic more than witches magic.

It also looks like Myrtle and Misty have healing powers (not related to resurrection), as Misty heals Kyle and Myrtle gives back eyes to Cordelia. We also see Cordelia making potions throughout the season, ability that could also count as magic.

In *Apocalypse*, Mallory pulls off tempus infinituum on three separate instances.

I'm sure there are some left, but I cannot think of more right now. I didn't see far enough of Apocalypse to add details from this season.

Comment: I just remembered that Misty resuscitates herself after she gets burned to death at the stake. Would you consider this different from vitalum vitalis? Also, why would you consider mind reading different from divination?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish For Misty's ressucitation, I always thought it was linked to Vitalum Vitalis, as it is her special talent. For the mind reading, I believe it's different from Divination as Divination is asking to spirits where some objects are located (for example) and Mind Reading is just listening to another one mind. With Mind Reading, you can only know whatever the person know,

I just remember another power, the Youth Stealing from the supreme in the firsts episodes: with a kiss, she steals the youth of one of the employees of the laboratory.

Comment: I suggested an edit with another example I remembered from *Apocalypse*